# How to use SQL Server Pivot with multiple criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table like below, that I would like transpose rows to colums, but I want to have columns for each month_product.

I know I could use SUM(CASE) for each product type and month like:

```
  SUM(CASE WHEN Month='July' AND Product='Prod1'THEN Revenue END)
```

However I would like to use pivot (I heard it's more efficient). I've been looking  arond how to use pivot, but the only ones I seem to be able to find is how to simply move the rows to columns, not combine rows to a column.

Could someone let me know whether this is possible or I have to stick with the good old case when method.

thanks,

from:

```
------------------------------------------------
|Month| Account| Product| Revenue|
------------------------------------------------
| July| Acct1  | Prod1  |1000
------------------------------------------------
| July| Acct1  | Prod2  |1000
------------------------------------------------
| Aug| Acct2   | Prod2  |1000
------------------------------------------------
```

to:

```
------------------------------------------------
|Account  | July_Prod1| July_Prod2| Aug_Prod2
------------------------------------------------
| Acct1   |     1000  |   1000    |
------------------------------------------------
| Acct2   |     -     |   -       |   1000
------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: `pivot` isn't more efficient. Syntactic sugar.

Comment: Oh, if it's not more efficient then it's much easier to do CASE WHEN thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Pivot each product by month separately, and then join the resulting (pivot tables) together and reorder the columns to suit your need.

Answer (score 0):

Concatenating the fields and pivoting after this:

```
WITH A as (
    select *, Month + '_' + Product WorkedField
    from Table1 A 
)

SELECT MONTH, ACCOUNT, sum(July_Prod1) July_Prod1, sum(July_Prod2) July_Prod2, sum(Aug_Prod2)    Aug_Prod2
FROM A    
pivot (sum(Revenue) for WorkedField in (July_Prod1, July_Prod2, Aug_Prod2)) B
GROUP BY MONTH, ACCOUNT
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/04b52/22/0)